# rust cross compiling for arm: skylake is not a recognized processor for this target

Tags: rust, arm

I'm following the rust book for embedded systems (this chapter https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/start/qemu.html)

When I "cargo build" the examples of the project referenced in the book (https://github.com/rust-embedded/cortex-m-quickstart) I get a lot of "skylake is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)" on the terminal.

Running "cargo size --bin app --release -- -A" as explained in the book doesn't yield the same result as in the chapter I linked above. Instead I get:

> app  :
>
> section              size   addr
>
> .debug_str          11062    0x0
>
> .debug_loc            171    0x0
>
> .debug_abbrev         773    0x0
>
> .debug_info         10121    0x0
>
> .debug_ranges          40    0x0
>
> .debug_macinfo          1    0x0
>
> .debug_pubnames      1482    0x0
>
> .debug_pubtypes      8247    0x0
>
> .ARM.attributes        57    0x0
>
> .debug_frame          100    0x0
>
> .debug_line          1048    0x0
>
> .comment               18    0x0
>
> Total               33120

There is no mention of the vector table, .text .rodata, .data. .bss

And the resulting file can't be loaded onto the board. So I guess it failed to cross compile.

Edit:
I didn't change anything in the .cargo/config provided with the project.
Here is the .cargo/config:

```
[target.thumbv7m-none-eabi]

# uncomment this to make `cargo run` execute programs on QEMU
# runner = "qemu-system-arm -cpu cortex-m3 -machine lm3s6965evb -nographic -semihosting-config enable=on,target=native -kernel"

[target.'cfg(all(target_arch = "arm", target_os = "none"))']
# uncomment ONE of these three option to make `cargo run` start a GDB session
# which option to pick depends on your system
# runner = "arm-none-eabi-gdb -q -x openocd.gdb"
# runner = "gdb-multiarch -q -x openocd.gdb"
# runner = "gdb -q -x openocd.gdb"

rustflags = [
  # LLD (shipped with the Rust toolchain) is used as the default linker
  "-C", "link-arg=-Tlink.x",
  # if you run into problems with LLD switch to the GNU linker by commenting out
  # this line
  #"-C", "linker=arm-none-eabi-ld",
  # if you need to link to pre-compiled C libraries provided by a C toolchain
  # use GCC as the linker by commenting out both lines above and then
  # uncommenting the three lines below
  # "-C", "linker=arm-none-eabi-gcc",
  # "-C", "link-arg=-Wl,-Tlink.x",
  # "-C", "link-arg=-nostartfiles",
  ]

[build]
# Pick ONE of these compilation targets
# target = "thumbv6m-none-eabi"    # Cortex-M0 and Cortex-M0+
target = "thumbv7m-none-eabi"    # Cortex-M3
# target = "thumbv7em-none-eabi"   # Cortex-M4 and Cortex-M7 (no FPU)
# target = "thumbv7em-none-eabihf" # Cortex-M4F and Cortex-M7F (with FPU)
```

Comment: Did you actually edit `.cargo/config` **in that folder** pointing to the target type you're targetting? This is typically what happens when you skip that step

Comment: @SébastienRenauld I didn't change anything in .cargo/config because it already points to cortex-M3, which is the example used in the book.  I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

You need a toolchain, specifically a linker, which supports the target processor.

`rustup target add thumbv7m-none-eabi` only adds the standard library -- it does not install a linker. Once you get a linker, edit your `.cargo/config file` to:

```
[target.thumbv7m-none-eabi]
linker = "arm-none-eabi-ld"

[build]
target = "thumbv7m-none-eabi"
```